# Raspbian - Read data from HID device

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian, hid

I got a measuring instrument which can measure light intensity and this instrument can be connected to a PC via USB.

I now want to be able to read  the values from the device via a Raspberry.

When the instrument is connected to the Pi, it shows up when entering 'lsusb' to the terminal and it is also listed under '/dev/usb' as hiddev1

But how can i actually grab the data from the device?
When i enter 'sudo cat /dev/usb/hiddev1' nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/), a cross-platform library for accessing Human Interface Devices.